# Correct cointegration p-value by sample size?

Tags: p-value, sample-size, cointegration

I have several time séries couples from which I compute cointegration p-value, then sort these couple by that p-value, starting from the lowest (for further VECM analysis on the top 100).

All couples have not the same length : some asset start after others, all finish at the same time (now), leading to time series with different length. I precise, 2 TS from the same couple have always the same length otherwise computing cointegration is not possible. When I find a couple with TSs having different nobs (different starting date), I crop the largest time series to the other and “align” them so that all points correspond in time.

We know that p-value shrinks when the sample size increases if H0 is false. I confirm that by generating a cointegrated pair and compute its p-value for different sample sizes, 100, 10k and 1m leading to very different p-value and its normal since the TSs are known to be cointegrated (H0 false).

From that context you may already guess the question :
Is it relevant to sort p-values of cointegration from time series couples  having different length, knowing that the p-value is ”underestimated” when the length is lower ? If not, how to compute a cointegration “score” that would take the p-value and account for their respective sample size, enabling to sort my TS couples with an homogenous unity ? Or is it just not relevant at all and I should always have the same length for all my TS ?

I precise that in my case, the sample is still large for all couples. It ranges from about 5k points to 15k points.